# Considering Combination of Vectors Using Regex in R

Tags: r, regex, vector, combinations

I was looking for some insight on how to tackle this problem.

For instance, let's say I have vectors A, B, C, and D and every possible combination between them. I want to write a generic function that would create a matrix like this:

```
    A   B   C   D   A&B A&C A&D B&C B&D C&D
A&B 1   1   0   0   2   1   1   1   1   0
A&C 1   0   1   0   1   2   1   1   0   1
A&D 1   0   0   1   1   1   2   0   1   1
B&C 0   1   1   0   1   1   0   2   1   1
B&D 0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   2   1
C&D 0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   2
```

The matching combination would be assigned a value of 2, while others that contain either value would be assigned a value of 1.
For instance, for A&B, A&B would be assigned a 2 while other vectors carrying either A or B would be assigned 1.

Right now I was considering on using Regex to check for overlapping names and creating a for loop. Would there be an easier/simpler way to tackle the problem?

Comment: "Would there be an easier/simpler way to tackle the problem?" Yes, I guarantee it (despite the fact I don't know R). I'm not sure why you thought regex was the option here.

Comment: Happens when you have used Regex before but can't think of simpler approaches - that's why I posted here asking for help.